# color graph nodes differently

Tags: r, graph, colors, nodes

I need to color nodes differently to plot graph communities (set of nodes) in R. For this case, I deal with 17 communities ( so I need 17 different color). to color nodes I use this command.

```
 V(g5)$color<- ifelse(V(g5)$name %in% V(g3)$name,com$membership+1, "white")

com$membership    
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4 4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 16 17 17 9 14
```

and to plot :

```
 plot(g5, vertex.color=V(g5)$name)
```

the problem that i get only 6 color that it repeat to the other communities. How can i correctly color this 17 communities differently?

Comment: You should post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's unclear how `g5` and `g3` and `com` relate to each other.

Comment: 'g5' and 'g3' are two graphs, and 'com' is the community structure i.e. it's means to which community a node belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just specify color with a numerical index, R will pull the colors from the current `palette()`. By default this contains 8 different colors.

```
palette()
# [1] "black"   "red"     "green3"  "blue"    "cyan"    "magenta" "yellow" 
# [8] "gray"
```

If you specify an index greater than 8, R will just loop around the index such that `1==9`.

You can change the pallette to contain more colors

```
palette(rainbow(17))
```

Or you could explicitly set the colors rather than specifying a color index.

```
mycols <- rainbow(17)
V(g5)$color<- ifelse(V(g5)$name %in% V(g3)$name,mycols[com$membership], "white")
```

This is probably "safer" than changeing the palette since that will affect all other plots as well.

```
g <- graph.ring(17)
V(g)$color <- rainbow(17)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Note: It's not that easy to find 17 different colors that you can easily distinguish by eye.